# get object from server.js app.get call into jS file for API call

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a server.js where I have all of my app.get calls and one of them I am trying to export an array to another javascript file to be used in a different API call. This is the endpoint I have:

```
app.get('/getInventory', checkNotAuthenticated, (req,res)=>{
var email = {user: req.user.email}; // used to obtain the email of the user thats logged in currently
var currUser = email.user;

pool
    .query(`SELECT itemname FROM inventory WHERE email = $1`, [currUser]) 
    .then((results)=>{
        console.log(results.rows);
        var myArr = [];
        results.rows.forEach((item)=>{
            myArr.push(item.itemname);
        });
        console.log(myArr);
        module.exports = {myArr};
        res.render('search')

    })
    .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err)
        
    })})
```

and this is the where I am trying to import the myArr. This myArr I am wanting inside of a js file that is calling an api when the user wants to search based on the return from the /getInventory endpoint.

```
const {myArr} = require('../server.js');
console.log('this is in the pscript file', myArr);
```

This provides an error saying

"pscripts.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

I looked on several stack overflow posts and thats how I came to this solution I have currently. not sure how else to manage this roadblock. I am using express and nodeJS. if there is any other imformation you need to help this question. I'll provide what I can. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 'require' runs before you export anything. You need to keep myArr in the local scope and fetch it on runtime.

```
let myArr = []
module.exports = ()=> myArr;

app.get('/getInventory', checkNotAuthenticated, (req,res)=>{
var email = {user: req.user.email}; // used to obtain the email of the user thats logged in currently
var currUser = email.user;

pool
    .query(`SELECT itemname FROM inventory WHERE email = $1`, [currUser]) 
    .then((results)=>{
        console.log(results.rows);
        myArr = [];
        results.rows.forEach((item)=>{
            myArr.push(item.itemname);
        });
        console.log(myArr);
        res.render('search')

    })
    .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err)
        
    })})
```

Then, each time you need the array just call it's function:

```
const exportedArray = require('../server.js');
const myArr = exportedArray();
console.log('this is in the pscript file', myArr);
```

Be aware, it will print an empty array because 'require' runs on runtime so myArr is empty. You should use it in another function:

```
const exportedArray = require('../server.js');
module.exports.foo = function(){
  const myArr = exportedArray();
  console.log('this is in the pscript file', myArr);
}
```

Now, if the 'foo' method gets called after server.js ran, myArr will print properly.

- NOTE **

By the way, it's not a good practice. If you need some data more than once, it should separate into a new module and get called everywhere needed,